# What is "semantically-driven reconstruction"

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I am going through [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.05698.pdf) paper to have a better understanding of how deep learning for Vision-related task works. I am not able to completely understand what exactly is "semantically-driven reconstruction" in this paragraph. -

> The model is trained sequentially, starting from the lowest layer.
> This allows to achieve good semantically-driven reconstruction results
> at smaller scales that are working with images of very low resolution
> and thus performing mostly global image manipulations.

Can anyone paraphrase this paragraph for easy understanding?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This PDF presentation](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Etingwuwang/semantic_segmentation.pdf) should help, but the basic idea is that rather than simply parsing the image on pixels (e.g. boundaries, contours, depth), a semantic reconstruction would allow for image features to be labeled and the scene to be "understood" in a more human sense. In the context of this paragraph, then, they claim that by training their each model layer separately (rather than training all layers at once), they can successfully label and manipulate image features, even if the image resolution is low.